# Why does iter borrow mutably when used in a pattern guard?

Tags: rust

This code:

```
fn t(r: &[u8]) {
    match r {
        _ if r.iter().any(|&x| x == b';') => {}
        _ => {}
    }
}
```

gives me the error:

```
error[E0301]: cannot mutably borrow in a pattern guard
   |
10 |         _ if r.iter().any(|&x| x == b';') => {}
   |              ^^^^^^^^ borrowed mutably in pattern guard
```

I understand that I can not borrow mutably in match patterns, but why does the compiler think that `r.iter()` borrows mutably? There is a separate method `iter_mut` for borrowing mutably.

And how can I check that `&[u8]` contains `b';'` without introducing separate functions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message is a bit more nuanced — `iter` doesn't borrow mutably, but the *result of `iter` is being borrowed mutably*. This is because [`Iterator::any`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.any) takes `self` by mutable reference:

```
fn any<F>(&mut self, f: F) -> bool 
where
    F: FnMut(Self::Item) -> bool,
```

Here's a reproduction:

```
struct X;

impl X {
    fn new() -> X { X } 
    fn predicate(&mut self) -> bool { true }
}

fn main() {
    match () {
        _ if X::new().predicate() => {}
        _ => {}
    }
}
```

I'd just check if the slice [`contains`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.contains) the value:

```
fn t(r: &[u8]) {
    match r {
        _ if r.contains(&b';') => {}
        _ => {}
    }
}
```

---

Realistically, this is an example of the borrow checker being overly aggressive. Mutably borrowing something from "outside" the match guard is a bad idea, but mutably borrowing something created in the match guard should be safe.

It's likely that this particular case would work when the borrow checker is rewritten to use Rust's MIR layer.

See also:

- [Rust issue #24535](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/24535)

Comment: Does it make sense for Iterator::any to take self by mutable reference?

Comment: @user12341234 yes, it does. You have to me able to mutate the iterator in order to call `next`, which updates the internal state of the iterator so it can return something different with each call.